# Delete dictionary in embedded list of dictionaries based on index number?

Tags: python, dictionary, indexing

I have an embedded list of dictionaries within a list, e.g.:

```
mylist = {'mydict': [{'A': 'Letter A','ay':'alpha'},
                     {'B': 'Letter B','bee':'beta'},
                     {'C': 'Letter C','cee':'cat'}]}
```

How do I delete one of the dictionaries in the list based on it's index number? The key:value pairs within the dictionary may change with each new iteration of the list, so it's necessary to use index number.

For example, if I chose to delete index[1] the list of dicts would result in:

```
mylist = {'mydict': [{'A': 'Letter A','ay':'alpha'},
                     {'C': 'Letter C','cee':'cat'}]}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your well-explained question. The answer is simpler than your details though, your question is the same as "how do I delete from a list by index"

```
items = [1, 2, 3]
del items[1]
assert items == [1, 3]
```

It is the same for your question

```
del my_list["mydict"][1]
```

Since `my_list["mydict"]` is your list.

As an aside, the way you describe needing to delete by index makes me think it is not the best method, it also will change the indices, so you may have some larger design level issues.

Answer (score 0):

To delete a dictionary contained in a list, you only need to do the same thing as you would access a dictionary that contains lists.

In your case, suppose you want to remove list elements from a dictionary which valued `{'B': 'Letter B','bee':'beta'}`:

```
>> mylist = {'mydict': [{'A': 'Letter A','ay':'alpha'},
                 {'B': 'Letter B','bee':'beta'},
                 {'C': 'Letter C','cee':'cat'}]}
>> {'mydict': [{'A': 'Letter A', 'ay': 'alpha'},
               {'B': 'Letter B', 'bee': 'beta'},
               {'C': 'Letter C', 'cee': 'cat'}]}
```

Then delete it using `del` keyword:

```
>> del mylist['mydict'][1]
>> {'mydict': [{'A': 'Letter A', 'ay': 'alpha'},
               {'C': 'Letter C', 'cee': 'cat'}]}
```

The syntax is more or less like this if you want to do something similar next time:

```
>> del dictionary['key'][index_of_list]
```